# How to detect end-of-file when using getline?

Tags: c++

```
while(getline(fileIn,line))
{

  fileOut <<line<<endl;

}


while(getline(fileIn,line))
{

  if(fileIn.eof())
   break;
  fileOut <<line<<endl;

}
```

I have tried both these pieces of code and the second one also reads past end-of-file and does not break. Can anyone tell me why?

I am just reading from a file and writing the lines out.

Answer (score 4):

The `getline` function returns a reference to the stream you're reading.  It evaluates to false if you try to read **past** EOF.  The stream is still in a good state when you read the last line of the file.  So you'll never reach the if-test in your second block of code.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a comma between "fileIn" and "eof()"??? (second example)

One thing I like to do, is enable [exceptions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/exceptions/) on my fstreams. YMMV:

```
ifstream file;
file.exceptions(ifstream::eofbit | ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit);
```

Comment: eofbit rarely does what the user wants and enabling exceptions for it is generally a very bad idea. It is enough to enable failbit to have full error handling but I would not recommend this either if the program reads until the end, as that would cause an exception to be thrown in a non-exceptional (but instead excepted) situation.

Comment: it was a typo i fixed it. but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

The first code is correct and it certainly does end the loop after no data is left in the file.